# Limiting which functions can be called by a thread

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

Let's say we have a multi-threaded Linux x86-64 executable (written in C, for example) with three threads: `main`, `consumer` and `producer`. Some of the functions are intended to use by some threads only. For example, the `produce()` function should only ever be called by the `producer` thread. I would like that if *another* thread (such as `consumer`) calls `produce()`, then we'd get a fatal error (a SIGABRT or SIGSEGV, for example).

One way to deal with this is to register the thread id, and check that the thread id calling `produce()` is in fact the `producer` thread id. If not, call `abort()`. That method unfortunately requires a runtime check for each function call, that maybe prohibitive if the function is in a hot path.

I'm wondering if there's another way, such as annotating and then moving all functions intended for `producer` only to their own section and remove executable memory accesses for all the other threads - my understanding is that this wouldn't work since `mprotect()` sets process-wide permissions - ?

Edit:
@AlanAu asks whether this check has to be done at runtime. It's not a requirement, but my understanding is that such a check would only work at runtime for non-trivial programs using functions pointers, for example.

Edit2:
I realize using processes would help address this, but as noted in the comments inter-threads communications is more efficient.

Comment: I assume your requirement is that this restriction has to be done at runtime and not at compile time? If so, can you please clarify your question to say that?

Comment: @AlanAu, I would like something that also works in non-trivial cases, e.g. involving function pointers. My understanding is that rules out compile time checks. I'll add that.

Comment: I'm sure it's because I don't know all your requirements. But it does beg the question why processes aren't used instead of threads if process isolation is a key requirement. I'm sure others will have the same thought too so perhaps clarify that as well.

Comment: as Alan au said `fork` may be better for this scenario, however the communication between processes is harder than with threads.

Comment: Ultimately, other than using separate processes instead of threads, I don't think there's much you can do except the run-time checking within functions that you say is too slow. But the real questions are (at least) two: (1) why do you think the programmers are so incompetent that they can't be trusted to do things right, and (2) why are the divisions between the sets of functions so rigid that it is desirable to fence them off like this yet the code (presumably) needs to share data structures more intimately than separate processes permit (and that's debatable if you use shared memory well).

Comment: *That method unfortunately requires a runtime check for each function call, that maybe prohibitive if the function is in a hot path.* Why do you think so? Did you test it? It's probably negligible. I mean, the work performed in `produce()` and others surely is far more complex and time consuming than a simple check on the thread id. Looks to me like you're falling in the early optimization trap.

Comment: Can you not control yourself when writing code or are you like a bunch of monkeys trying to bang out Shakespeare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One /rather hackey/ way of doing this is to make pointers for these and calling the pointers instead of the functions themselves. Example:

```
void disallowed_call(void)
{ abort(); }

void testfunc(void)
{
     printf("Hello, world!\n");
}

void childcode(void (*notrestricted)(void), void (*restricted)(void);)
{
     printf("Non restricted call:\n");
     *notrestricted();
     printf("Restricted call:\n");
     *restricted();
}

int main()
{
     fork();
     if (getpid() == 0)
     {
          childcode(&testfunc, &testfunc);
     }
     else
     {
          childcode(&testfunc, &disallowed_call);
     }
     return 0;
}
```

That might be a bit more complicated than you were looking for, but it should work. The runtime check is done only once.

Comment: That could actually work: a variation would be to have the public functions be TLS pointers, and initialize them with valid static functions when they're callable, and leave them as-is when they're not.

Comment: I wouldn't leave them "as-is", but would implement a "not permitted" function. Another way is to have an API function that calls the functions when allowed, or fails when not, but that is REALLY complex relative to the task